# Javascript date : go back to the last week number of year_n when on week number 1 of year_n+1

Tags: javascript, date

Initially, I got the number of week this week of month of 2020 which is week 43 `(Oct 19 2020 - Oct 25 2020)`.
I also have two buttons which serve as `next` and `previous`.

When I click `next` button, the date changes to `(Oct 26 2020, Nov 1 2020)` as well as the week number to 44. 
The same way goes to `previous` button. All is working almost fine, However, when I reach year `2021`, the week number becomes 1 of course. and when I click previous again, it goes to the last week number of year `2021` instead of 2020.

My code for incrementing and decrementing weekly is this:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate()+7) //increment
date.setDate(date.getDate()-7) //decrement
```

I know the reason why it does not go back to the last week of 2020 because I only deducted 7 days.

However, I can't figure out how to go back to the last week of 2020 when I click previous.
Any idea?

**UPDATE:** Just now, I noticed, when I'm on the last week of 2020 and click next, Instead of going to '2021', It jumps to '2022'.. damn, I really hate working with dates on javascript.

Comment: This might be a bug in your `getWeek` implementation? Might be worth posting it.

Comment: @BenAston I think I got the `getWeek` properly, its just that this is how javascript date works.

Comment: Btw, I have an update. Hope someone has answers to this :(

Comment: You might get a better answer if you post more of the relevant code. The code you posted looks OK.

Comment: The code shown should work, the error is elsewhere. Show more code.

Answer (score 0):

I concluded. using native javascript date is such a hassle,
instead, I used momentjs.

all of the long code simplified by using

```
moment(date).add/subtract(no_of_days, 'd');
```

It automatically do the thing for you. no need to get the number of week and the year.

Comment: Historical note: the Date object built-into JS is a clone of the corresponding Java object that existed in the 1990s.